# How would you use multiprocessing / threading to increase the speed of a c++ program?

Tags: c++, multithreading, optimization, multiprocessing

I have a function func that does the following:

```
int func(int n){
    counter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        if(check(i)){
            counter++;
        }
    }
}
```

for some function check. I'm trying to find all numbers n for which func(n) is equal to exactly 1 million, for some range around 4,000,000 < n < 4,100,000. Currently the program checks each n in around 3 seconds, but checking 100,000 numbers is taking too long. My computer has 6 cores so I figure multiprocessing would speed things up dramatically. I don't really have experience with multiprocessing and I'm not the best at c++. If theres a good guide on this please point me towards it too. Thank you!

Edit: The check function is basically a function that checks the distance between a point (0,0) and (i, n-i) in a triangular plane. The order in which you check numbers is not important. It's a solution to https://research.ibm.com/haifa/ponderthis/challenges/December2023.html where check(n) finds the amount of distance radii between n and n+1. I know the nested while() loop seems like it would cause a lot of delay but I'm fairly certain the time complexity is actually ~O(n).

```
typedef long long ll;
ll rad2(ll horizontal, ll vertical){
    return horizontal * horizontal + vertical * vertical + horizontal * vertical;
}
int func(ll m){
    ll horizontal = m + 1;
    ll vertical = 1;
    ska::flat_hash_set<ll> rads;
    while (vertical < (m + 1) && horizontal >= 0){
        while (m * m < rad2(horizontal, vertical)){
            if (rad2(horizontal, vertical) < (m + 1) * (m + 1)) {
                rads.insert(rad2(horizontal, vertical));
            }
            horizontal--;
        }
        vertical++;
    }
    return rads.size();
}
```

Comment: Split the loop and share loop chunks to 6 threads. But this not a solution. The bottleneck is `check` that should be optimized.

Comment: Need more details, especially for the `check()` function.  For example, can the `check()` function be run in parallel?  Can the loop be unrolled?

Comment: What does `check()` do?   The basic principle is that the changing order of loop iterations shouldn't affect anything.  You code currently calls `check(0)` .... `check(n)` in order.   If changing the order at all affects the result (and there are many reasons that might or might not happen) then multiprocessing (which relies on getting the same result, even if the sequencing of calls changes, or if they are done concurrently) won't help you.

Comment: Reminder:  there is no default guarantee that threads will be run on separate CPUs.  If they are, is the memory set up so that the separate CPUs are not in contention for memory access?

Comment: Reminder:  the OS is running other tasks than yours.  The OS may be delegating other whole tasks to other cores or threads to other cores.

Comment: When using multiple threads, the threads must execute longer than the overhead of setting them up, maintaining them, and destroying them.  Otherwise, they are hindering your program's performance.

Comment: You want multithreading, not multiple processes. Look up the `<execution>` header, and use the parallel version of `std::for_each`. It accepts a container, and to avoid writing the indices to a big array, use `std::views::iota`.

Comment: Here are some optimization rules: 1) Reduce requirements; 2) Reduce operations; 3) Choose more efficient algorithms; 4) Change the design for parallel execution; 5) Change implementation to be *cache-friendly*.

Comment: I use `std::async` quite effectively on a 6 core cpu. Generally see a 4-5x speed improvement splitting up multiple FFTs such that the memory for each fits in the level 2 cache.

Comment: If you need abbreviation macros, you should take a keyboarding class, or figure out how to program "hot keys", which are keyboard shortcuts to print out text.  They actually slow down the build process because the C++ Preprocessor has to do text replacement, essentially modifying the source code, before it is presented to the compiler.  The abbreviation macros make the reader have to and look for the definition of `ll`.  Most of the contests and online-judge, don't measure your development time, so take your time and type slowly.

Comment: Pay heed to Thomas and doug's notes about cache. You can get everything else right and still lose because you accidentally set up a deviant case where the threads take turns trashing each other's cache, forcing frequent, if not constant, reloading of data.

Comment: Note in the original formulation, `func(n)` is easily calculated from `func(n-1)` at a cost of just one call to `check()`. You can therefore build a table of `check()` values, dividing the work among threads, and then consolidate the results in a final pass. The point is that you need to understand the problem and look for ways of expressing it in ways that parallelize.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach. Use `std::async` to spawn N tasks.
The work is divided up so that each task works on an
assigned subset of the numbers:

```
std::mutex mutex;           
std::vector<size_t> found;       // save found values of n here                                                                                                  

//                                                                                                                                                               
// Spawn tasks and divide up the work;                                                                                                                           
// task i works on number n iff n % i == 0                                                                                                                       
//                                                                                                                                                               
constexpr size_t numTasks = 6;   // choose based on # of available cores                                                                                         
std::vector<std::future<void>> futures(numTasks);
for (size_t task = 0; task < numTasks; task++) {
    futures[task] = std::async(std::launch::async, [&,task]()
    {
        for (size_t n = 4000000; n < 4100000; n++) {
            if (n % task == 0 && func(n) == 1000000) {
                mutex.lock();
                found.emplace_back(n);
                mutex.unlock();
            }
        }
    });
}

//                                                                                                                                                               
// Wait for all tasks to finish                                                                                                                                  
//                                                                                                                                                               
for (size_t task = 0; task < numTasks; task++) {
    futures[task].get();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With Intel TBB:

```
#include <oneapi/tbb/parallel_for.h>

int func(int n)
{
    counter = 0;
    tbb::parallel_for(0,n,[&counter](int i) { 
        if ( check(i) )                     counter++; 
    });
}
```

Comment: This is undefined behavior if (I assume) `counter` is not atomic. I'd use `tbb::parallel_reduce`.